# How can I access a query parameter inside an nginx location?

Tags: nginx, variables, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to setup an nginx auth_request location that can verify user requests using two options, the default one uses an authorization header in the client header request that is sent directly to the proxy_pass. This first one works as expected. The second one is meant to detect whether an access token(`token`) query parameter is available in the client request and change the verification path as well as the proxy method. However, it seems that the variables `query_parameter`, `args`, and `arg_token` which are meant to have this value are all null inside the auth location. Below is my nginx-config configmap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  location-snippets: "  
    auth_request /auth;
  server-snippets: " 
    location = /auth {      
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') { return 204; } 
      if ($request_uri !~ '/api/v') { return 200; } # All none api requests 

      set $method POST;
      set $backend_path verify;

      if ($arg_token) {
        set $method GET;
        set $backend_path tokens/$arg_token/verify;
      }

      internal;
      resolver                kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;
      proxy_method            $method;
      proxy_pass              http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:3000/api/v1/users/$backend_path;
      proxy_pass_request_body off;
      proxy_set_header        Content-Length '';
      proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }"
```

A sample client request may look like: `GET: /api/v1/apples?token=123`
What could I be getting wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am currently using a workaround of picking the token from the `request_uri` variable since it also has it but would very much like to understand why my code snippet above won't work.

Comment: if ($request_uri ~* 'token=(?<token>[^&]+)') { set $method GET; set $backend_path tokens/$token/verify; }